# Stop lyx from compiling

Tags: lyx

Is there any way to stop Lyx from compiling?

(I am using Lyx with knitr, so the compilation can take very long. Sometimes, I often find errors while Lyx is still compiling. As I cannot cancel the compilation, I have to wait until the compiler gets to the error in order to start compilation again ...)

Comment: There is a bug request asking for a button to stop the compilation: http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/10108 . In the meanwhile, you can try to stop the spawned processes (pdflatex, knitr...) and lyx will give up at some point (not ideal).

Comment: @G.M. I would say add that as the answer. There is no other way to solve it currently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a bug request asking for a button to stop the compilation: http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/10108. In the meanwhile, you can try to stop the spawned processes (pdflatex, knitr...) and lyx will give up at some point (not ideal).

Comment: #10108 is marked as duplicate. Ongoing exports are documented in https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/7900 (last change 11 months ago).

Answer (score 3):

It will be possible via <kbd>Document</kbd> → <kbd>Cancel Background Process</kbd> when Lyx 2.4 is released:

> As of LyX 2.4, this is possible. When a file is exported, a new menu entry, "Cancel Background Process", appears on the Document menu: Selecting it will indeed cancel the export process. This can also be done by clicking on the 'spinner' that appears in the status bar when a file is being exported in the background.

Source: https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/NewInLyX24#cancel